# sforce.one.navigateToURL on click vs javascript

Tags: salesforce1-app, navigation

I am using the following code in visual force page to launch a page from a non-salesforce site (external site with sales process documentation).

```
function openSalesPilot(e){
    if ((typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce!=null)) 
    {
        alert('sforce');
        sforce.one.navigateToURL(spUrl );
    }
    else 
    {
        alert('js');
        window.open(spUrl);
    }
    if (e!=null) e.preventDefault();
}    
window.onload = function(){
    var spLink = document.getElementById('salesPilotLink');
    spLink.addEventListener("click",openSalesPilot);
    openSalesPilot();
}
```

The idea is when the page loads it automatically launches a page, and when they come back to Salesforce they have the option to click on the link again. This works fine in the browser.

but in Salesforce1 when we `navigateToURL` from the `onload` event it opens in a browser with a "done" button in the upper left that returns them to SF1. If the user clicks on the link and runs the same code, but I only see a flash of the browser window before it closes.

I've also tried just using `window.open()`, but when it runs from script it opens with a "Close" button in the upper left, and when it runs from click it opens with a "Done" button.

How can I make this consistent? Is there some salesforce event I need to wait for before running my script?

Comment: I think you need to move `e.preventDefault();` statement before your if/else block

Comment: I tried that, no luck. What I ended up doing was only adding the listener for non-SF1 and letting the <a> tag handle the click. To get that working right I had to remove the target='_blank', which is why I still need to catch the event from browsers because I need the link to open in a new tab.